# Google Analytics v4 crashes with custom global config

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I've tried adding a custom global config file to my app but it keeps causing the app to crash. If I take out the custom gloabl config file everything works fine.

The specific version of events that leads to a crash is:

- Start app, this works fine first time round
- kill app using a task killer
- re-load app, the app no longer starts, often just loading a black screen.

There's no log to indicate an error; the app just won't load second time round.

I've added the code i've used below, mostly copied from the google documentation

Global config addition to manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/global_config" />
```

Global config file

```
<string name="ga_appName">AppName</string>
<string name="ga_appVersion">Version1.1.0</string>

<!--Remember to set to WARNING log level for production -->
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

<!--time before hit is sent to google -->
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

<!--Remember to set to FALSE for production version-->
<bool name="ga_dryRun">true</bool>
```

Tracker code in Application class

```
HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER,
}


// creates analytics tracker
public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
        t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

Code to init tracker in BaseActivity class

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

I'm at a bit of a loss to fix this with no log output and quite sparse documentation so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I found a way round the problem. I removed the global_config.xml and took away its reference in the manifest file.

Instead I set the global config parameters in the getTracker method

```
// creates analytics tracker
public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setDryRun(true);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1000);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
        t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

The app now runs fine with custom global configs and no crashes!